# Java this returns the object consumed by the method and not the base object

Tags: java

I'm attempting to override the compareTo method in Java. For some reason, this(or the base object) is overridden and compared to the the "other" object or the object inserted into the method.

Does anyone know why this would end up happening? I don't think I am overriding "this" anywhere?

When testing I created 2 polynomials:

- Polynomial 1: 42, -7, 0, 5
- Polynomial 2: 37, -2, 0, 0, 6
- This is expected to be 42, -7, 0, 5
- "other" is expected to be: 37, -2, 0, 0, 6
- However, "this" ends up being 42, -7, 0, 5

Code:

```
public class Polynomial implements Comparable<Polynomial>
{
private static int[] coefficients;

public Polynomial(int[] coefficients){
    if (coefficients.length < 1) {
    this.coefficients = new int[]{0};
    }
    else {
    int current_position = coefficients.length -1;
    while(coefficients[current_position] == 0 && current_position > 0){
        current_position--;
    }
    this.coefficients = new int[current_position +1];
    System.arraycopy(coefficients, 0, this.coefficients, 0, current_position +1);
    System.out.println("this" + this);
}
};

@Override public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
    for (int exponents = 0; exponents < coefficients.length; exponents ++){
        if (exponents > 0){
            sB.append (" + ");
        }
    sB.append("(");
    sB.append(Integer.toString(coefficients[exponents]));
    sB.append(")z^");
    sB.append(Integer.toString(exponents));
    }
    return sB.toString();
};

public int getDegree(){
    if(coefficients.length <= 1){
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return coefficients.length - 1;
    }
};

public int getCoefficient(int k){
    if(k >= coefficients.length)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return coefficients[k];
    }
};


public static long evaluate(int x){
    ArrayList<Integer> toSum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int summedValue = 0;
    toSum.add(coefficients[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i <= coefficients.length -1; i++){
        int value = x;
        for (int y = 0; y < i -1; y++){
            value = value * x;
        }
        value = value * coefficients[i];
        toSum.add(value);
    }
    summedValue = toSum.stream().mapToInt(value -> value).sum();
    return summedValue;
};

@Override public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
    Polynomial that = (Polynomial) other;
    if (this.getDegree() != that.getDegree()) return false;
    for (int i = this.getDegree(); i >= 0; i--)
        if (this.coefficients[i] != that.coefficients[i]) return false;
    return true;
};

@Override public int hashCode(){
    return Arrays.hashCode(coefficients);
  };

public int compareTo(Polynomial other){
    System.out.println("this" +  );
    System.out.println("other" + other);
    return 0;
    System.out.println("this " + this.getDegree());
    System.out.println("other " + other.getDegree());
    if (this.getDegree() < other.getDegree()) return -1;
    else if (this.getDegree() > other.getDegree()) return +1;
    else {
        for (int i = coefficients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("thisC " + this.coefficients[i]);
    System.out.println("otherC " + other.coefficients[i]);
       if (this.coefficients[i] < other.coefficients[i]) return -1;
        if (this.coefficients[i] > other.coefficients[i]) return +1;
    }
    }
    return 0;
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] c1 = {42, -7, 0, 5};
    int[] c2 = {37, -2, 0, 0, 6};
    Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(c1);
    System.out.println("p1" + p1);
    Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial(c2);
    System.out.println("p2" + p2);
    System.out.println("compare" + p1.compareTo(p2));

}

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should make your `coefficients` not static. Secondly your method `evaluate` shouldn't be static either.
And then your logic is correct at the method `compareTo`:

```java
public int compareTo(Polynomial other) {
    if (this.getDegree() < other.getDegree()) return -1;
    else if (this.getDegree() > other.getDegree()) return 1;
    else {
        for (int i = coefficients.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (this.coefficients[i] < other.coefficients[i]) return -1;
            if (this.coefficients[i] > other.coefficients[i]) return +1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```